# Jacobian of the inverse of two functions

Tags: calculus

My professor is asking us to find the inverse of the following functions and then compute the integrals of the inverses.

It's been awhile since I've done calculus and this is one of two problems I have no clue on.

The functions are

$u=e^x\cos(y), \ \ \  v=e^x\sin(y)$

I tried and failed to get the equations to resemble what I remember from calculus... x=u+v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hints:*

Note that $u^2 + v^2 = e^{2x}$ and $v/u = \tan y$. Solve for $x$ and $y$.

Also, the Jacobian matrix $(x,y) \to (u,v)$ has an inverse which is the Jacobian for $(u,v) \to (x,y)$.

Comment: I can simplify the expression involving the tangent pretty easily by using arctan, but the first equation would require a log, perhaps. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I believed I solved the problem. I used y=atan(v/u)   and x=1/2(ln(u^2+v^2)) to solve the derivatives and the Jacobian. My answer was 2/(x^2+u^2)